# forbid PHP CLI to load an extension present in the ini config file

Tags: php, command-line, phpunit, php-extension

I have a php installation where i want to have several extensions loaded via ini files. both for apache and for command line.

but for a few unit tests, i do not want those extensions loaded.

can i call php or phpunit in a way that it will not load certain extensions?

let's say, my php.ini on the system is:

```
extension = A.so
extension = B.so
extension = C.so
```

i want to run php this time with A and B only. Is there some option like `php --exclude-extension=C.so` or `php -d "extension=!C.so"` that eluded me from the manual?

Comment: There is an option for giving a `php.ini` file as an argument. Maybe you can have two different `php.ini`s?

Comment: i was hopping something i could add with "-d" command line switch. just for future proofing. If i could remove the extension i need removed, in the future it would just work. if i create a new ini, in the future, it must be updated. but yes, that's plan B for sure.

Comment: Usually PHP already uses different `php.ini`s for different SAPIs.

Comment: @KingCrunch you are right. I have those extensions being loaded on my cli's ini file. but for one unittest in particular, i don't want one of them loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.

there's no extension list exclusion in php.